# Google Spreadsheet locale settings set to US on upload

Tags: google-drive-api

This appears to be an old issue:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/1Cj9waTA82o/lDemjoPe5wUJ (Date Format Change on Upload Fault)
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/NnYKK_23hFE (Incorrect regional settings on uploading a spreadsheet)

I have been unable to find any new information on this bug (?), so I'm asking about it again here.

It's fairly easy to replicate. Create a new Google Spreadsheet, then set its locale to anything other than US. Then using either the Google Drive API or the web app's import functionality, upload a new revision. Upon closing and re-opening the spreadsheet, the locale would have changed to US.

Is there any existing workaround or is a fix in the works at all? Thanks.